Python3 - msticpy - how to update Azure Sentinel Incident label?
I am attempting to update an Azure Sentinel incident label using msticpy. I can successfully modify other properties, but labels is not accepting the API call.
Could anyone provide insight?
Environment Python 3.10
Azure Machine Learning Studio notebook
msticpy 2.11
    from msticpy.data.azure import AzureData, MicrosoftSentinel
    azs = MicrosoftSentinel()
    azs.connect()
    azs.update_incident(incident_id = "INCIDENTID8", update_items = {'labels': 
    [{'labelName': 'test', 'labelType': 'User'}]})

Error:
HTTPStatusError: Client error '400 Bad Request' for url 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTIONID/resourceGroups/RESOURCEGROUP/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/WORKSPACE/providers/Microsoft.SecurityInsights/incidents/INCIDENTID?api-version=2020-01-01' For more information check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400

You need to use the get_incident method to return an incident object first. Then you can modify or add labels from there.
from msticpy.sectools.incident import IncidentLabel

incident_id = "GUID HERE" # You can pass a name to get_incident, but it's not guaranteed to be unique
incident = azs.get_incident(incident_id)

new_label_name = "test"
new_label_type = "user"
new_label = IncidentLabel(label_name=new_label_name, label_type=new_label_type)

incident.labels[new_label_name] = new_label

azs.update_incident(incident)


Hi Jamie, thank you. This gives an error saying "NameError: name 'IncidentLabel' is not defined"

@glwallum Ah OK. You need to import it. I've updated my answer. See top line.

Am I missing something with the packages? sectools does not have an Incident Label attribute
